# Call StrFormatByteSize64 function from within C#

Tags: c#, winapi

how can I call the StrFormatByteSize64 function from the Win API from within C#? I'm trying the following code, but without success:

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
static extern void StrFormatByteSize64(ulong qdw, char[] pszBuf, uint cchBuf);

char[] temp = new char[128];
ulong size = 2000;
StrFormatByteSize64(size, temp, 128);
Console.WriteLine(temp);
```

The function's documentation can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759971%28VS.85%29.aspx

Thank you!

Comment: try adding the ref keyword to the pszBuf parameter.


static extern void StrFormatByteSize64(ulong qdw, ref char[] pszBuf, uint cchBuf);
... nm.. that didn't work.

Comment: @gbogumil: That passes the *pointer* to the array by reference, not the contents.

Answer (score 3):

This works, although it may not be the cleanest way:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{    
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
    static extern void StrFormatByteSize64(ulong qdw, StringBuilder builder,
                                           uint cchBuf);

    static void Main()
    {
        ulong size = 2000;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(128);
        StrFormatByteSize64(size, builder, builder.Capacity);
        Console.WriteLine(builder);
    }
}
```

I'm afraid I don't know much about interop - it could be that you don't need to specify the  initial capacity of the `StringBuilder`, for example. I'm not sure :( Anyway, it should provide you with a starting point for further investigation.

Comment: Thank you! It works pretty well. Finally a nice solution to convert bytes to other memory units, such as KB, MB, GB... I'll investigate further the matter of the StringBuilder class.

Comment: Better to use `StrFormatByteSize64(size, builder, (uint) builder.Capacity);` IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `[Out]` before `char[]`.

---

Edit:

I can't believe I didn't notice this sooner, but another problem is that your function is *not* `void`! It returns a pointer. You might want to fix that if you want it to work. :)

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
static extern IntPtr StrFormatByteSize64(long qdw, [In] StringBuilder pszBuf,
                                         uint cchBuf);

//...
ulong num = 10000000;
var sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
if (StrFormatByteSize64(num, sb, (uint)sb.Capacity) != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    //Conversion successful... do stuff
}
```